# Yamaha YT3600 Erratic Revs

Tags: yamaha, lawnmower

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDeyq.jpg

Could anyone indicate where to look first? I’ve not had much luck. Checked the air filter, fuel lines. It runs smooth when it’s under high load (mower deck on and down)

Cheers!
Andrew

Comment: Engine is trying to stall, but the governor kicks in to raise the rpm, carb is dirty or in need of adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for info. I took the carb apart and it looks clean. Jets are all clear. There are only two adjustment screws, one idle and don’t know about the other. Adjusting the unknown screw while running makes no difference. I’ve put it back to where it was. Any advice on where to look? Unfortunately can’t find the specific manual for this mower

Comment: Make model and serial number?